# Image uploader shouldn't remove unused link references

Tags: feature-request, editor, uploader

When editing a post and using the image uploader, any unused link references are completely removed.

For example, this post has three image references, only one of which is used (`[3]`) in the body of the post:

> [image]

After uploading a fourth image, references `[1]` and `[2]` are completely removed (and the remaining references are renumbered to become `[1]` and `[2]`):

> [image]

I sometimes write link references before using them in the body of the post and sometimes remove images temporarily before reinserting them elsewhere in the post so this is inconvenient.

(Note: this also applies for the iOS app, having the same behavior)

Comment: This would have to be changed on the web version too. This is how the image uploader and link inserter have worked everywhere pretty much since they were created.